# jquery select by id or by class?

Tags: jquery

I have five different input controls on a page, each with a different id and name, and a class as well.

```
<input id="txtName1" name="txtName1" class="jName" type="text" />
<br />
<input id="txtName2" name="txtName2" class="jName" type="text" />
<br />
<input id="txtName3" name="txtName3" class="jName" type="text" />
<br />
<input id="txtName4" name="txtName4" class="jName" type="text" />
<br />
<input id="txtName5" name="txtName5" class="jName" type="text" />
```

Which is the more efficient manner when using jquery to select a group of inputs by to register the blur event? The reason I ask is because I actually have 20 of these input controls on the page and I want the jquery select to be as quick as possible.

**1) Select by tag id:**

```
$(document).on("blur", "input[id*='_txtName']", function ($e) {
  alert("blur event successful");
})
```

or

**2) Select by class:**

```
$(document).on("blur", ".jName", function ($e) {
  alert("blur event successful");
})
```

**EDIT:** 
My intent here is to hook the blur event up to all of the input elements in the code above. Sorry for the confusion here, folks.

Comment: _each with a different id and name_? Are you sure?

Comment: @undefined - Doh! Good catch! Sadly, I even proofread it once before hitting the submit button. Good thing I don't get paid to proofread, I guess.

Comment: ["Premature optimization is the root of all evil"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) - this is a micro optimization and you're very likely to not see any difference. It's a time waster, and you're better off making your code readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things:

1. You are using the same id value on all those elements.  Don't do that, they're supposed to be unique.
2. Looking up by class is much faster in this case, since a class selector is faster than an attribute selector.

Performance test: http://jsperf.com/id-regex-vs-class

In the `HTML` on that test, I did change your id values to be unique.  I'm also using the attribute starts with selector instead of the ends with.

Comment: -1, really?  I even show proof backing up my answer.  Care to elaborate on why this was downvoted?

Comment: I didn't downvote you and not sure why they did. Anyway, I had mistakenly left all of my input tags with the same ID, which I didn't mean to. I edited my original question though and fixed the typos. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No worries.  Since you're selecting multiple elements to wire up your event, use the class selector, it'll be faster than the attribute selector.  Now if you were targeting a single element, use the id selector all day.

Comment: @Gromer He's only selecting one element to wire up the event, the `document`.

Comment: @Gromer - Ok, I think you nailed it on the head. I had suspicions that the class selector was faster in this case, but I wasn't sure. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @KevinB - Unless I've got my selector messed up in my question (but I don't believe so), my intent is to wire-up the blur event with all of the text input elements.

Comment: @Jagd right, but you are using event delegation, so really only 1 event is being bound, directly to the document. your code is not selecting all input elements, it is just testing the e.target to see if it matches the selector.

Comment: I think we're talking about the same thing here. I'm wiring one event to multiple inputs tags.

Comment: This for example would be a more relevant jsperf. http://jsperf.com/id-regex-vs-class/2 Sure, it still shows that selecting by class is faster, but notice how many more elements both of them get through. It works through the code so quickly that you will not notice a difference in either case unless your events are happening tens of thousands of times per second.

Comment: @KevinB, regardless, he had a couple options for the selector.  A class selector will be faster than an attribute selector, and that's what his question boiled down to, which is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try benchmarking your code with JSPerf, and you'll have your answer. :)

http://jsperf.com/

Seriously, though, efficiency isn't the only thing to worry about, and performance is going to be affected by a number of other considerations, including the elements on, and the structure of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Your sub-selector performance doesn't make much of a difference considering it's only ever going to be looking at a single element at a time (the one that triggered the event). If you really want to improve performance, pick a better context element than the document.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "a better context element". Is there a more efficient way to do a jquery select than what I'm doing (other than #id, of course)?

Comment: That's just it, you aren't selecting the inputs at all! you are selecting the document. Your events have to bubble all the way up to the document before your handler is triggered. If your "context" was the form that the inputs are in for example, the event would only need to bubble up to the form before your handler is triggered.

Comment: Ah... interesting. I kind of get it now, but I'm not sure exactly how to go about changing what I have to do what you're saying. So I'll have to spend some more time googling it to figure it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @jagd basically, it would be `$("#formid").on("blur","theselector",handler)` assuming that the form doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: Sure it does. The answer is it's irrelevant.

Comment: The question is asking the equivalent of "Which is faster, 1+1 or 1+1" since both cases are exactly the same as far as initial execution.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at this fiddle: [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eLWE7/)

You'll see that the ***** selector with the ID definitely makes it a little bit slower. (Also note that I'm selecting the element 50,000 times, which would probably never happen).  The class selector in this case is definitely faster, but the difference is rather insignificant.

From the jQuery website: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

> This is the most generous of the jQuery attribute selectors that match
>   against a value. It will select an element if the selector's string
>   appears anywhere within the element's attribute value. Compare this
>   selector with the Attribute Contains Word selector (e.g.
>   [attr~="word"]), which is more appropriate in many cases.